# Diamond /rotated square border

Tags: css

I'm struggling to figure out how to add a border like the image here. Diamond/square rotated border. I've tried border images  but I can't seem to get them to load.

both this

```
    border-image: url('path-to-your-png') 33% round;
    /* border-image: url('content/uploads/2018/07/border.png')  33% round;
    border-width: 0 0 20px 0;
    margin-left: 1px; */
```

and this

```
    border-image-source: url('content/uploads/2018/07/dots.svg');
    border-image-slice: 33% 33% ;
    border-image-repeat round;
```

Haven't worked. (also I removed the link urls but I'm positive the links I'm using in the real code are correct.

[Border I'm looking to recreate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjfWi.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS border-image Property would do the job.

See docs: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_border_images.asp

```css
.border-diamond {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 30 round;
}
```

```html
<div class="border-diamond">
  Content here
</div>
```

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image the rules can be a bit weird to work out at times though!

Comment: AH ! I didn't have a transparent one set up . THANK YOU OMG THANK YOU

Comment: Glad its works. Please, read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Wow thank you I didn't even know that was an option. Took me a minute to find it too